# Does std::ctype always classify characters by the "C" locale?

Tags: c++, unicode, character-encoding, locale

cppreference says `std::ctype` provides character classification based on the classic "C" locale. Is this even true when we create a locale like this:

```
std::locale loc(std::locale("en_US.UTF8"), new std::ctype<char>);
```

Will the facet of `loc` still classify characters based on the "C" locale or the Unicode one? If it classifies by the former, why do we even specify the locale name as "en_US.UTF8"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard requires the **default-constructed** `std::ctype<char>` to match the minimal "C" locale via `§22.4.1.3.3[facet.ctype.char.statics]/1`

> `static const mask* classic_table() noexcept;`
>
> *Returns:* A pointer to the initial element of an array of size `table_size` which represents the classifications of characters in the "C" locale

the classification member function `is()` is defined in terms of `table()` which is defined in terms of `classic_table()` unless another table was provided to the `ctype<char>`'s constructor

I've updated cppreference to match these requirements more properly (it was saying "C" for `std::ctype<wchar_t>` too)

To answer your second question, the locale constructed with `std::locale loc(std::locale("en_US.UTF8"), new std::ctype<char>);` will use the ctype facet you specified (and, therefore, "C") to classify narrow characters, but it's redundant: narrow character classification of a plain `std::locale("en_US.UTF8")` (at least in GNU implementation) is exactly the same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <locale>
int main()
{

    std::locale loc1("en_US.UTF8");
    const std::ctype_base::mask* tbl1 =
         std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(loc1).table();

    std::locale loc2(std::locale("en_US.UTF8"), new std::ctype<char>);
    const std::ctype_base::mask* tbl2 =
         std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(loc2).table();

    for(size_t n = 0; n < 256; ++n)
        assert(tbl1[n] == tbl2[n]);
}
```

Comment: So must we use `std::ctype_byname` to reconfigure the character classification to a certain locale?

Comment: @0x499602D2 it's just one way. Look at the [constructors of std::locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale) for others

Comment: Is there a difference between `locale("en_US", new ctype<char>)` and `locale("de_DE", new ctype<char>)` (assuming those are valid locale names)? Will the `ctype` object still classify base on "C" and not on those respective locales? If so, what is the point of the different locale names in the first place?

Comment: @0x499602D2 The two locales would be different in every facet except the ctype facet, which you made identical, e.g. streams would print numbers and dates differently if imbued with these locales. Neither locale would have a name (`object.name()` would return `*`)

Answer (score 1):

From what I read in the working draft I have for C++11 N3376 §22.4.1.1, `std::ctype<char>` is supposed to do this:

```
Class ctype encapsulates the C library <cctype> features. istream members 
are required to use ctype<> for character classing during input parsing.

The specializations required in Table 81 (22.3.1.1.1), namely ctype<char> and 
ctype<wchar_t>, implement character classing appropriate to the 
implementation’s native character set.
```

It has no mention of the C locale anywhere in there, chances are cppreference might be referring to the functions found in `<cctype>`.

Comment: So in Windows the native character set will be "C", right? So why should it operate on the C locale and not on the locale to which I install it?

Answer (score 0):

In C, the C locale applies until you change the locale with `setlocale()` from `<locale.h>`.  The same is likely true of C++, though you also probably have other mechanisms for setting the locale.

Your statement appears to create a locale; it is not clear that it makes that locale into the default locale, though.  That locale can then be used to specify the comparison:

ISO/IEC 14882:2011 (the C++ 2011 standard) has section 22.3 entitled **Locales**.  It says, in part:

```
// 22.3.3, convenience interfaces:
template <class charT> bool isspace (charT c, const locale& loc);
template <class charT> bool isprint (charT c, const locale& loc);
```

Also, a little later in the standard, it says:

> **22.3.1.5 `locale` static members [locale.statics]**
>
> `static locale global(const locale& loc);`
>
> 1 Sets the global locale to its argument.
>
> 2 *Effects:* Causes future calls to the constructor locale() to return a copy of the argument. If the
>      argument has a name, does
>   `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, loc.name().c_str());`
>   otherwise, the effect on the C locale, if any, is implementation-defined. No library function other
>   than `locale::global()` shall affect the value returned by `locale()`. [ *Note:* See 22.6 for data race
>   considerations when `setlocale` is invoked. — *end note* ]
>
> 3 *Returns:* The previous value of `locale()`.

---

> So I have to change the global locale before running the above line if I want `std::ctype` to classify based on "en_US.UTF8"?

What I read from the initial quote is that, given your `loc` you could write:

```
if (isspace(ch, loc)) { ... }
```

specifying the locale to be used explicitly.  If you don't want to do that, then you need to call `std::locale::global(loc)` to set the global locale, so unadorned invocations of `isspace()` will work:

```
if (isspace(ch)) { ... }
```

Comment: Question: The signature of `isspace` you just showed doesn't take a default argument, so how are you sending it just one??

Comment: The signature I quoted is a template from `<locale>`; the single-argument invocation is using `isspace()` from `<cctype>`.

Comment: But still what is the reason for creating the line that I made above? Why should `std::ctype` be tied to the global locale and not the locale that I create it with?

Comment: Your statement `std::locale loc(std::locale("en_US.UTF8"), new std::ctype<char>);` creates a variable, `loc`; it does not change anything to do with `std::ctype` (it just uses a `std::ctype`, and it uses a `std::locale`, too, with the given name).

Comment: So since `std::ctype` is tied to the global locale by default, I should use `std::ctype_byname` and send it a locale name through its constructor instead?

Comment: Pass...I'm not sure...and I need to concentrate on 'real' work.

Comment: Well as long as you're honest. :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: This does not answer either question (whether std::ctype uses "C" and whether  the hybrid locale `loc`'s ctype facet does,  too)